# Error message "Error: openxlsx can only read .xlsx or .xlsm files" in R 4.1.3

Tags: r, import, xls

I have a script I was using a few months ago, and I was asked to re-output it using new source data. Now I get the message "Error: openxlsx can only read .xlsx or .xlsm files."

Of course, it IS an .xlsx file.

Not only that, I went back and ran the same script on the old source file (which worked), and...I get the same error!! I haven't changed any code, but my version of R has been updated by the administrators from 3.6 to 4.1.3 (I work in a virtual environment). I have confirmed that openxlsx version 4.2.5 is installed.

I've seen in other posts that people recommend using other packages to read xlsx files. That is not an ideal option here for administrative reasons (getting permission to install new packages can be very time-consuming and may blow deadlines), and I've started pursuing that option, but in the meantime, does anyone have any ideas?

Unfortunately, changing the format (i.e. exporting as csv and using read.csv) is also not an option, because we're auditors and doing that will break the audit trail.

Comment: "...we are auditors and doing that will break the audit trail": in my world, auditing in a different environment to that in which the work was originally conducted would also most likely break the audit trail...

Comment: I realize it's likely difficult to provide a reproducible question (perhaps proprietary data), but I don't know what we can do without seeing _something_. I haven't seen volatile sensitivity in openxlsx due to R versions. Can you add more context, including the before and after versions of R and openxlsx? Are any other packages used that might contribute? How confident are you on the validity of the `.xlsx` file? Some tools create them and Excel _can_ read (fix) them, but they are sometimes fractured slightly, breaking `openxlsx`.

Comment: @Limey not sure what your point is. My question does not concern our audit procedures.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a colleague of mine solved the problem.

The source file has the extension ".XLSX". In order for openxlsx to read the file, you have to change the extension IN THE CODE to ".xlsx" (in my case at least, I didn't even have to change the actual extension of the file--just the quoted reference in the code), although other colleagues say they have had to do this.